# RDF Vocabulary for describing Uri components

Tags: uri, metadata, rdf, semantic-web, vocabulary

### Is there a known RDF vocabulary for describing metadata of Uri components?  (e.g. scheme, authority, querystring, etc.)

**Update**  I have been able to find a [DublinCore term resource for URI](http://dublincore.org/documents/2012/06/14/dcmi-terms/?v=terms#URI), but the extent of information communicated in the corresponding RDF document is that "a URI is a DataType", which is much more limited than what I need.  The RDF description is below:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://purl.org/dc/terms/URI">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">URI</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">The set of identifiers constructed according to the generic syntax for Uniform Resource Identifiers as specified by the Internet Engineering Task Force.</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"/>
    <dcterms:issued rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2000-07-11</dcterms:issued>
    <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2008-01-14</dcterms:modified>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Datatype"/>
    <dcterms:hasVersion rdf:resource="http://dublincore.org/usage/terms/history/#URI-003"/>
    <rdfs:seeAlso rdf:resource="http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

Comment: As I'm sure you've discovered, this is a remarkably hard thing to search for using Google, since most descriptions of OWL ontologies mention "IRI", "URI", or "URL."

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, it's like looking for the solution to a `StackOverflowException`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### w3.org/wiki/URI

I’m not sure what to make of it, but in the w3.org wiki there is a [**URI** page](http://www.w3.org/wiki/URI) containing a small vocabulary with classes like `URI`, `IRI`, `Scheme`, and `UWI`. The vocabulary URI for the concept "URI Scheme" would be `http://esw.w3.org/topic/Scheme`.

#### CoIN

Related, but probably not exactly what you need, seems to be [**CoIN** (The Composition of Identifier Names)](http://code.google.com/p/court/wiki/COIN):

> The CoIN vocabulary defines a set of classes and properties used to descibe what properties of a resource constitute components of a URI.

(See also: [URI Templates](http://code.google.com/p/uri-templates/))

#### uri4uri.net

There is also [uri4uri.net](http://uri4uri.net/), created as an April fool joke, for:

> URIs, URI fragment identifiers, Internet Domains, Mime Types, File Suffixes, URI Schemes.

See the vocabulary at http://uri4uri.net/vocab. It contains URIs for all the relevant URI parts.

An example HTTP URI containing all parts would be: [http://foo:bar@bbc.co.uk:80/index.html?a=1&b=2](http://uri4uri.net/uri/http%3A%2F%2Ffoo%3Abar%40bbc.co.uk%3A80%2Findex.html%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2)

The [generated Turtle](http://uri4uri.net/uri.ttl/http%3A%2F%2Ffoo%3Abar%40bbc.co.uk%3A80%2Findex.html%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2) includes:

```
<http://uri4uri.net/uri/http%3A%2F%2Ffoo%3Abar%40bbc.co.uk%3A80%2Findex.html%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2> 

  rdf:type uriv:URI ;
  skos:notation "http://foo:bar@bbc.co.uk:80/index.html?a=1&b=2"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI> ;
  uriv:scheme <http://uri4uri.net/scheme/http> ;
  uriv:host <http://uri4uri.net/domain/bbc.co.uk> ;
  uriv:port "80"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger> ;
  uriv:user "foo" ;
  uriv:pass "bar" ;
  uriv:account <http://uri4uri.net/uri/http%3A%2F%2Ffoo%3Abar%40bbc.co.uk%3A80%2Findex.html%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2#account-foo> ;
  uriv:path "/index.html"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ;
  uriv:suffix <http://uri4uri.net/suffix/html> ;
  uriv:filename "index.html"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ;
  uriv:queryString "a=1&b=2"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ;
  uriv:query <http://uri4uri.net/uri/http%3A%2F%2Ffoo%3Abar%40bbc.co.uk%3A80%2Findex.html%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2#query> .
```

Comment: uri4uri.net was discontinued, which is quite uncool! However, I have started hosting the resolver and vocabulary at https://purl.org/uri4uri/, hopefully available indefinitely.